# UITextField will not autoresize when editing a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I am working on a table under iOS, I added a couple of cells, and each cell has one UITextField added as a subview. An excerpt:

```
UITextField *t = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 5.0, 220.0, 20.0)];
// here I set properties for t ...
t.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[cell addSubview:t];
cell.autoresizeSubviews = YES;

// if needed, I set the UIImageView for the cell
if (...) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
    t.frame = CGRectOffset(text.frame, 33, 0);
}

[t release];
```

What happens? When I enter the editing mode for the tabel, I'd expect that each cell will resize to make the red minus sign visible, and that the UITextField will move to right to remain aligned to the cell itself, as the other components. But this do not happen.

Also, I tried to change the `autoresizingMask` param using various combinations of `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`, `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, but without success.

Am I doing something wrong here? Should I change the way I add the text field as a subview?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your views to the contentView of the cell:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:t];
```

Comment: I didn't try just that ... I tried adding to the `textLabel`, to the `detailTextLabel` ... cool, thank you!